# How to change text and background color?

Tags: c++, windows

I want every character to be a different color.

for example,

```
cout << "Hello world" << endl;
```

- **H** would be red
- **e** would be blue
- **l** would be orange
  and so on.

I know this can be done, I just don't know the code for it.

and I want to change the background color to white. How would I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no (standard) cross-platform way to do this. On windows, try using `conio.h`.
It has the:

```
textcolor(); // and
textbackground();
```

functions.

For example:

```
textcolor(RED);
cprintf("H");
textcolor(BLUE);
cprintf("e");
// and so on.
```

Answer (score 9):

[SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, FOREGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_RED);
```

This would produce red text on a white background.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the function `system`.

```
system("color *background**foreground*");
```

For background and foreground, type in a number from 0 - 9 or a letter from A - F.

For example:

```
system("color A1");
std::cout<<"hi"<<std::endl;
```

That would display the letters "hi" with a green background and blue text.

To see all the color choices, just type in:

```
system("color %");
```

to see what number or letter represents what color.

Comment: it changes the whole console color and is not portable in other OS.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdafx.h> // Used with MS Visual Studio Express. Delete line if using something different
#include <conio.h> // Just for WaitKey() routine
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); // For use of SetConsoleTextAttribute()

void WaitKey();

int main()
{

    int len = 0,x, y=240; // 240 = white background, black foreground 
    
    string text = "Hello World. I feel pretty today!";
    len = text.length();
    cout << endl << endl << endl << "\t\t"; // start 3 down, 2 tabs, right
    for ( x=0;x<len;x++)
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, y); // set color for the next print
        cout << text[x];
        y++; // add 1 to y, for a new color
        if ( y >254) // There are 255 colors. 255 being white on white. Nothing to see. Bypass it
            y=240; // if y > 254, start colors back at white background, black chars
        Sleep(250); // Pause between letters 
    }

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, 15); // set color to black background, white chars
    WaitKey(); // Program over, wait for a keypress to close program
}


void WaitKey()
{
    cout  << endl << endl << endl << "\t\t\tPress any key";
    while (_kbhit()) _getch(); // Empty the input buffer
    _getch(); // Wait for a key
    while (_kbhit()) _getch(); // Empty the input buffer (some keys sends two messages)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use PDCurses library. (http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Colors are bit-encoded. If You want to change the Text color in C++ language There are many ways. In the console, you can change the properties of output.[click this icon of the console and go to properties and change color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2zXm.jpg)

The second way is calling the system colors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Changing Font Colors of the System

    system("Color 7C");
    cout << "\t\t\t ****CEB Electricity Bill Calculator****\t\t\t " << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t  ***                MENU           ***\t\t\t  " <<endl;

    return 0;

}
```